# Oracle 11g: For the same table different query perfomance, seems like indexes destroyed for some data

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, oracle11g, sql-tuning

I have a problem with data querying (Select) perfomance.

in the table Receivables we have account_id which is Indexed.
When I run below script then for Account_ID=2003975183 it's OK, but for Account_ID=900025281 process is slowly.It's happend after the oracle server was unexpectedly stopped.
***Both accounts have nearly the same count of rows.***

**SQL Script for Accounts:**

```
SELECT nvl(sum(invoice_amt),0) inv_amt
FROM ardb.receivables
WHERE
   acct_id = 2003975183
  AND  entry_date >= trunc(SYSDATE)
  AND  entry_date < trunc(SYSDATE) + 1;
```

***According the trace data it seems like that Index is not working properly, is it?***

Both traces for Fast ans Slow query attached:

[FAST_QUERY_RESULT_TRACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1A8b.jpg)

[SLOWLY_QUERY_TRACE_RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ncXL.jpg)

Kindly check and help to fix the problem.
    Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you `gather stats` of the table  receivables and then run your query once again and see.

Comment: I forgot to tell: 1) tables data partitioned and 2) already did gather stats. No effect. By the way before the gather stat num rows of stats and partition were the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
After run this script and increase share pool size query working fine and in trace I can see index scan (before it was not):

```
ANALYZE INDEX IDX_RECEIVABLES_ACCTID VALIDATE STRUCTURE online;
```

Comment: You you use dbms_stats package to gather table/index stats.

Comment: BobC, what did you mean?

Comment: Opps. I mean that you should be using the DBMS_STATS package to gather stats, rather than the ANALYZE. The ANALYZE command is deprecated for stats gathering

Comment: I used the DBMS_STATS package, but it did not help, so after that used Analyzed.